# subsetting the first row of repeat data based on multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have repeat rows of ethnicity data of random people with dates on when the ethnicity was assigned. I would like to assign each person only one ethnicity category (white, asian, black, other, mixed) based on these conditions: (1) if the person has multiple ethnicity, then the most common one (highest ethnicity_n) will be assigned. (2) if the patient has multiple ethnicity in equal numbers (e.g. 1 mixed, 1 Asian, 1 Other) then the most recent one will be assigned. I organized my data in a way so that I have a count of each ethnicity per patient and I wrote code to make the date of ethnicity in descending order. However, when I run code to get the first row of my organized table I end up with random ethnicity assigned for each person.

| person | ethnicity | ethnicity_n | ethnicity_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | white | 4 | 04/09/2019 |
| 1 | white | 4 | 04/09/2018 |
| 1 | white | 4 | 04/09/2017 |
| 1 | white | 4 | 04/09/2016 |
| 1 | other | 1 | 04/09/2015 |
| 2 | asian | 1 | 04/09/2019 |
| 2 | other | 1 | 04/09/2018 |
| 2 | mixed | 1 | 04/09/2017 |
| 3 | black | 2 | 04/09/2016 |
| 3 | black | 2 | 04/09/2015 |

I used this code to make the table above

```
df %>%
  group_by(person,ethnicity_n,ethnicity_date) %>%
  arrange(person,ethnicity_n,desc(ethnicity_date))
```

I want the final table to look like this

| person | ethnicity | ethnicity_n | ethnicity_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | white | 4 | 04/09/2019 |
| 2 | asian | 1 | 04/09/2019 |
| 3 | black | 2 | 04/09/2016 |

I tried all of these codes to get the second table but each time the ethnicity is not meeting the conditions that i want

```
df %>%
  group_by(person,ethnicity_n,ethnicity_date) %>%
  arrange(person,ethnicity_n,desc(ethnicity_date)) %>% 
  slice(1L)

df %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  arrange(person,ethnicity_n,desc(ethnicity_date)) %>% 
  slice(1L)

df %>%
  group_by(person,ethnicity_n,ethnicity_date) %>%
  arrange(person,ethnicity_n,desc(ethnicity_date)) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==1)

df %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  arrange(person,ethnicity_n,desc(ethnicity_date)) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==1)
```

#### Data:

```r
df <- structure(list(person = c(
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L,
    3L
), ethnicity = c(
    "white", "white", "white", "white", "other",
    "asian", "other", "mixed", "black", "black"
), ethnicity_n = c(
    4L,
    4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), ethnicity_date = c(
    "04/09/2019",
    "04/09/2018", "04/09/2017", "04/09/2016", "04/09/2015", "04/09/2019",
    "04/09/2018", "04/09/2017", "04/09/2016", "04/09/2015"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
    NA,
    -10L
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem was that your `ethnicity_date` was a character vector, rather than a `Date`.

I have assumed it's in month-day-year format but if it's day-month-year format you can just change `format = "%m/%d/%Y"` to `format = "%d/%m/%Y"`.

Note that as we are using `max()` functions for `ethnicity_date` and `ethnicity_n`, it is not necessary to `arrange()` the data in order first. You will need to supply `na.rm=TRUE` to the `max()` function if you have any `NA` values in either column.

```r
df |>
    mutate(
        ethnicity_date = as.Date(
            ethnicity_date,
            format = "%m/%d/%Y"
        )
    ) |>
    group_by(person) |>
    filter(
        ethnicity_n == max(ethnicity_n)
    ) |>
    filter(
        ethnicity_date == max(ethnicity_date)
    ) |>
    slice(1L) # in case there are still ties

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
# # Groups:   person [3]
#   person ethnicity ethnicity_n ethnicity_date
#    <int> <chr>           <int> <date>
# 1      1 white               4 2019-04-09
# 2      2 asian               1 2019-04-09
# 3      3 black               2 2016-04-09
```

I kept your `slice(1L)` at the end in case there is an individual with more than one row with the same `ethnicity_n` and `ethnicity_date`, but you can remove it if you want to keep both rows in that case.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Thank you for adding a sample dataset, that is much easier.

I think `slice_max()` is what you are looking for, see below. It is also better to format the date properly first

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(ethnicity_date = as.Date(ethnicity_date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")) %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  slice_max(ethnicity_n) %>% 
  slice_max(ethnicity_date) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 × 4
# person ethnicity ethnicity_n ethnicity_date
# <int> <chr>           <int> <date>        
# 1      1 white               4 2019-09-04    
# 2      2 asian               1 2019-09-04    
# 3      3 black               2 2016-09-04
```